# Create macro which sets x-axis min and max but want to call macro when min max cells change values

Tags: excel, vba, charts, axis

Below macro runs fine but i need it to run when the min or max values change so that the chart axis automatically rescales. I have tried 'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)' but to no success. Would anyone know why below runs on its own but not when I try and call it via worksheet change?

```
Sub Axis_Update()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("DASH")

ws.ChartObjects("T_CHART").Activate
With Application.ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
.MinimumScale = ws.Range("AXIS_MIN").Value
.MaximumScale = ws.Range("AXIS_MAX").Value
.MajorUnit = ws.Range("AXIS_TICK").Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is that the values change due to formula recalculation and you need the `Worksheet_Calculate` event instead.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Thank you BigBen